# OrbitControls - how to make the camera look the opposite way

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, orbitcontrols

I'm using `react-three-fiber` with `OrbitControls` to display a textured sphere with a backside material. I want my camera to orbit inside that sphere and around it's center. `OrbitControls` does that just fine, but it always points at the target which is in the center. I want it to point in exact opposite direction (to the outside) while keeping all the features of `OrbitControls`

```
<Canvas camera={{ fov: 45, position: [1, 0, 0] }}>
  <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <mesh>
      <sphereGeometry args={[110, 32, 32]} attach="geometry" />
      <meshBasicMaterial side={BackSide}>
        <GradientTexture
          stops={[0, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 1]}
          colors={['red', 'green', 'black', 'blue', 'pink']}
          size={1024}
        />
      </meshBasicMaterial>          
      <OrbitControls target={[0, 0, 0]} enableZoom={false} reverseOrbit={true}/>
    </mesh>
  </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

Right now I'm using something like this and it looks ok, but I don't have the ability to zoom in a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone who might stumble upon similar issue - don't do it like this.
I actually managed to achieve this by wrapping `OrbitControls` in a component and using `useFrame`:

```
function Controls() {
  const controlsRef = useRef<OrbitControlsImpl>(null);

  useFrame(({ gl, scene, camera }) => {
    if (!controlsRef.current) {
      return
    }
    const { x, y, z } = controlsRef.current.object.position
    camera.lookAt(x * 2, y * 2, z * 2)
    gl.render(scene, camera)
  }, 1);

  return <OrbitControls
    target={[0, 0, 0]}
    ref={controlsRef}
    minDistance={10}
    maxDistance={80}
  />
}
```

But then I got my wheel and horizontal panning reversed and couldn't find a way to work around it.
Eventually, the optimal solution was to switch to a `PerspectiveCamera`, disable zoom for `OrbitControls` and writing my own wheel handler that used `camera.zoom` property:

```
const { camera, gl: { domElement } } = useThree();

function handleWheel(this, ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
    ev.preventDefault()
    let newZoom = camera.zoom + -1*(ev.deltaY/1000)
    if(newZoom < 1) newZoom = 1
    if(newZoom > 10) newZoom = 10
    camera.zoom = newZoom
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}
domElement.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
```